# How to implement conditional render in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Below is the JS (jQuery) code of autocomplete's result function. You can see there's some lines where I print out `<li>`s containing some `data` properties (that come in as a result of automcomplete's AJAX call).

How could I rewrite this so that `<li>` would be conditionally rendered based on whether the property contains any value being either `int` or `string` (not empty string or whitespace) or something else that can be represented as `string`?

```
$(".clients-dropdown").result(function (event, data, formatted) {
    if (data) {
        // set the hidden input that we need for Client entity rematerialize
        $(".client-id").val(data.client_id);
        if (data.ClientName && data.Address1 && data.postalcode && data.postname) {
            $(".client-address").html(
                    "<li>" + data.ClientName + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + data.Address1 + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + data.postalcode + " " + data.postname + "</li>"
            );
            $(".client-details").html(
                    "<li>" + data.PrettyId + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + data.VatNo + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + data.Phone + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + data.Mobile + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + data.Email1 + "</li>" +
                    "<li>" + data.Contact + "</li>"
            );
        }
    }
```

Also, for the AJAX call, should my server side action return `null` when there's a `null` for a property in the database or empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function that will test the property for whitespace.

```
var getListItem = function(prop){
    if(!!$.trim(prop))
        return '<li>' + prop + '</li>';
    return '';
};

$(".clients-dropdown").result(function (event, data, formatted) {
    if (data) {
        // set the hidden input that we need for Client entity rematerialize
        $(".client-id").val(data.client_id);
        if (data.ClientName && data.Address1 && data.postalcode && data.postname) {
            $(".client-address").html(
                    getListItem(data.ClientName) +
                    getListItem(data.Address1) +
                    getListItem(data.postalcode + ' ' data.postname)
            );
            $(".client-details").html(
                    getListItem(data.PrettyId) +
                    getListItem(data.VatNo) +
                    getListItem(data.Phone) +
                    getListItem(data.Mobile) +
                    getListItem(data.Email1) +
                    getListItem(data.Contact)
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Note sure if that's what you want.

```
$(".clients-dropdown").result(function (event, data, formatted) {
var new_li = function(data) {
   $.trim(data) != "" ? "<li>" + data + "</li>" : ''
}
if (data) {

    $(".client-id").val(data.client_id);
    if (data.ClientName && data.Address1 && data.postalcode && data.postname) {
        $(".client-address").html(
                new_li(data.clientName) +
                new_li(Address1) + ... // you get the idea
        );
    }
}
```